# Strange usage in node-mysql documantation

Tags: javascript, node.js, bind, chain

while reading the node-mysql documantation i saw a usage as i pasted below

```
var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM posts');
query
  .on('error', function(err) {
    // Handle error, an 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
  })
  .on('fields', function(fields) {
    // the field packets for the rows to follow
  })
  .on('result', function(row) {
    // Pausing the connnection is useful if your processing involves I/O
    connection.pause();

    processRow(row, function() {
      connection.resume();
    });
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    // all rows have been received
  });
```

i wonder how they use this events those can be used with the name whatever
user names the query `query` in example when i create custom events i name them first for example `var foo=new events.EventEmitter` and after this in whole page i have to use  it as `foo.on("someEvent")`
but here they somehow bind the var created by user as event name in example code user names the mysql query as `query` and the event emitter has the same name somehow

and second question how is that possible to chain events as they use

```
.on("event").on("anotherEvent")
```

this question may sound strange but i really wonder how this works and it will change my code design completely

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your first question is. Can you perhaps explain a bit more or provide examples to help understand the question better?

Comment: updating the question now @mscdex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query` is just your variable name for what is an instance of a [`Query`](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js) in the node-mysql lib. You get access to all the functions that object exports.

`on` is inherited from [`EventEmitter`](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js) in the node.js core. The key thing is that calling `on` returns "itself" i.e. `this`:

> Returns emitter, so calls can be chained.

This allows you to chain calls to `on`

Comment: how i can return event emitter out of cb function i dont understand it will not be returned to  the variable

Comment: ah i see it is returned by the module itself